# dlookup not working for other month than MAY

Tags: ms-access-2003

I am using dlookup (date = date) its fine when the date is of "May" but when I put date of any other month like 1/6/19 the dlookup remains silent.

in Dlookup if date is of MAY its fine but not working when date id of JUN the code I am using is as below
Me

`Total = DLookup("Total", "Dailycash", "Cdate =#" & sdate & "#")`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "1/6/19" is not a month. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Also, what does "date = date" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a proper format to the date value expression:

```
Total = DLookup("Total", "Dailycash", "Cdate = #" & Format(sdate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```